# Can't use nested variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't use variables declared in nested blocks.

Example:

```
if(condition){
    var test = "success";
    {
```

If I try to use the test variable i get a compilation error:

> CS0103: The name 'test' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Looks like you didn't _even_ show the real code that generates this error message. On which line exactly you get it?

Comment: The workaround is to move the variable outside the scope.

Comment: What does the extra opening curly brace on the 3rd line belong to? You can't just open a curly brace for no reason if it's not a part of some construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the variable outside the block you need to declare it outside the block.

As the variable has to have a value even if you don't run the code in the block, you either have to set an initial value:

```
string test = null;
if (condition) {
  test = "success";
}
```

or use an `else` block to set a value otherwise:

```
string test;
if (condition) {
  test = "success";
} else {
  test = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because its a `local` variable and accessible only in those braces. Not outside.

To make it accessible outside as well, you might want to declare it out of the function or out of the method or on the start of the page as per your need.

Have a look on the `local` and `global` variables as well the concept of `scope` of a variable.

That should do it.

Comment: If i declare it outside, any assignment is not seen outside the block, and i get: CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'test'

Comment: That is because you might be writing it like this : `var test;`. Write it like this  : `var test="";` or `var test=1;` or anything. Just assign it a value for initialization purpose and then you can play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write this as:

```
var test = condition ? "success" : "failure";
...
// use test as required.
```

(Replace "failure" with whatever value you want for test when the condition is false).